# Conversion from GeoJSON to TopoJSON renders a single path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, map-projections

So I had a GeoJSON of [UK Counties](https://www.nemezisproject.co.uk/2012/05/21/google-maps-api-uk-counties-overlay-kml/) (was actually KML before) and converted it to TopoJSON using the [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) node package.

```
topojson -o map-england.json -p --simplify-proportion .2 topo-map-england.json
```

This worked well in terms of reducing the file size and with simplification, it drastically improved the panning and zooming of the map.

[image: uk counties]

However, in the conversion, my **map now consists of a single path** where before I had a path for each county.

[image: map path]

Before I was able to add a `mouseover` event that added a CSS class to the hovered path and that applied a colour change. Now however, when I move my mouse over any county, **the whole map changes in colour because the whole map is one giant path**!

How does one overcome this? Have I gone about this the wrong way?

Comment: Are you able to show/link your source GeoJSON? And maybe to be complete add the commandline string you're using to make the conversion.

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4206573 -- use `.features` on the structure returned by `topojson.feature()`.

Comment: @iH8 updated question with information you asked.